# How to make a sympy Symbol a real number without creating a new one?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a sympy symbol `x = Symbol('x')` and I want to transform it into a real number without creating a new `symb = Symbol(x.name, real=True)`. How can I do this?

Consider the following example:

```
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
expr = x - x.conjugate()
expr
```

[image]

I want to make `x` real so that the above expression always simplify to 0.

**EDIT**: I also tried to evaluate the symbolic expression by using [`refine`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/refine.html), but it doesn't seem to work:

```
from sympy import Symbol, refine, Q

x = Symbol('x')
refine(x - x.conjugate(), Q.real(x))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware if there is some function that automatically performs that substitution, however you are already on the right track to create your own function:

```py
def symbols2real(expr, *s):
    d = {sym: Symbol(sym.name, real=True) for sym in s}
    return expr.subs(d)

expr = x - x.conjugate()
symbols2real(expr, x)
# out: 0
```

Edit to clarify: you cannot modify in-place existing symbols because SymPy uses immutability, so you have to create new symbols and replace the existing ones.